# Magento-2.3.3 getting "Request validation failed for action" error while accessing front controller url when receiving data from third party webhook

Tags: error, controllers, magento2.3.3

I have created one front controller in my project in order to receive data from third party webhook (e.g. sendgrid). However, when webhook access this url magento logs below error in debug.log file

***Request validation failed for action "Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Email\Index\Interceptor" [] []***

Does anyone has idea regarding this? I already gone through couple of stack overflow solutions but it didn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I got the solution. Sorry for late reply.

This issue generally comes when some parameters are not passing through the request which your controller serves and used to validate that specific request. So if you know those exact parameters then you can simply add it while calling controller from third party service.

Or you need to bypass the validations done by magento while accessing controller from third party service. In order to do that you need to write below 2 functions in your controller.

```
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```

This will resolved your issue.

That's all!

Comment: Thnaks for your help

Comment: Thanks @CarlosHernanAguilarHurtado. Please upvote my answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickW: one upvote from me as well as it worked like a charm for me. Thanks.

Comment: @PratikNavapara i am also facing same issue, and i added this code also, but still getting same error.

Comment: @sam, this should be working fine. Sorry but I don't know any other solution for this error.

Comment: @PratikNavapara Can you tell me in which file i can put this code..?

Comment: @Nikul, you need to put this code in your respective controller file.